# Workday Soap API - User Name/Password

Tags: soap, workday-api

I am trying to call the Workday Integration API.  I am able to connect but am getting a invalid username or password message.  My question is - where do I put this information?  I don't see anything in the wsdl where I can put the user name or password.

[Launch_Integration](https://community.workday.com/custom/developer/API/Integrations/v24.2/Launch_Integration.html)

Thanks for any help!
Warren

Answer (score 15):

For some reason, finding the correct auth method is difficult in the Workday documention, in fact I'm not sure even if it's mentioned anywhere. 
If you're using Workday Studio, you may use the Web Service Tester. That will generally allow you customize and form your request and will show you various authentication options.

However if you don't you may use the below envelope for your requests. 
In the BODY you need to add the particular WS request you want to use (such as Launch Integration).

```
<env:Envelope
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <env:Header>
        <wsse:Security env:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>yourusername@yourtenant</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password
                    Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">**YOURPASSWORD***</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>

    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: That is how I figured it out as well.  With that info, you can auth via SoapUI, Java , or other languages via WS-Security and  the yourUserName@yourTenant  user name form (as you mention). The user account also needs to be in a group that has access to LaunchIntegration.  If the Studiointegration will run as the launching user, it also needs access to the required Workday web services.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following blog post extremely helpful when consuming Workday services.  It covers a bunch of the gotchas, including handling the security aspect.

http://dovetailsoftware.com/hr/gcox/2014/06/13/getting-started-workday-web-services-using-c/

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the Integration API but would imagine that it works just like the others that I have used, like Compensation, Benefits, ...
See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132244/workday-soap-api-how-to-authenticate). You should have an "IntegrationPortClient" object generated in the stub that you can use to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java, here's the code for handling the credentials. Can't remember where I got it originally, maybe somewhere on the Workday Community website.

Example usage, hrPort and hrService are from class generated from the wsdl:

```
HumanResourcesPort hrPort = hrService.getHumanResources();

BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) hrPort;

WorkdayCredentials.addWorkdayCredentials(bp, 
            config.getWdIntegrationUsername(), 
            config.getWdIntegrationPassword());
```

Here is the class:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.mycompany.workdayservice.data;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class creates a handler that will add the WS-Security username and
 * password to the to the SOAP request messages for a client side proxy.
 * 
 */
public class WorkdayCredentials implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    /** Namespace for the SOAP Envelope. */
    private static String SOAPENVNamespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";

/** The prefix that will be used for the SOAP Envelope namespace. */
private static String SOAPENVPrefix = "soapenv";

/** Namespace for the WS-Security SOAP header elements. */
private static String WSSENamespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";

/** The prefix that will be used for the WS-Security namespace. */
private static String WSSEPrefix = "wsse";

/**
 * The WS-Security URI that specifies that the password will be transmitted
 * as plain text.
 */
private static String WSSEPasswordText = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText";

/**
 * The user name that will be sent in the WS-Security header on the SOAP
 * request message. This is of the form systemid@tenant.
 */
private String username;

/**
 * The password that will be sent in the WS-Security header on the SOAP
 * request message.
 */
private String password;

/**
 * This method created an instance of the WorkdayCredentials class and adds
 * it as a handler to the bindingProvider supplied.
 * 
 * @param bindingProvider
 *            The client stub to which the handler will be added. The most
 *            convenient way to obtain the required bindingProvvider is to
 *            call one of the getPort methods on the Service class for the
 *            Web service and then cast the returned object to a
 *            BindingProvider.
 * @param username
 *            The id and tenant name for the user. This is of the form
 *            systemid@tenant.
 * @param password
 *            The password for the system user.
 */
public static void addWorkdayCredentials(BindingProvider bindingProvider,
        String username, String password) {
    List<Handler> handlerChain = bindingProvider.getBinding().getHandlerChain();
    handlerChain.add(new WorkdayCredentials(username, password));
    bindingProvider.getBinding().setHandlerChain(handlerChain);
}

/**
 * Creates a WorkdayCredentials handler and initialises the member
 * variables. In most cases, the addWorkdayCredentials static method should
 * be used instead.
 * 
 * @param username
 *            The id and tenant name for the user. This is of the form
 *            systemid@tenant.
 * @param password
 *            The password for the system user.
 */
public WorkdayCredentials(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

/**
 * Returns null as this handler doesn't process any Headers, it just adds
 * one.
 */
public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
    return null;
}

/**
 * Adds WS-Security header to request messages.
 */
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
    Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) smc
            .get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
    if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {
        addWSSecurityHeader(smc, username, password);
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Returns true, no action is taken for faults messages.
 */
public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
    return true;
}

public void close(MessageContext messageContext) {
}

/**
 * Adds a WS-Security header containing a UsernameToken to a SOAP message.
 * 
 * @param smc
 *            The SOAPMessageContent to which the WS-Security header will be
 *            added.
 * @param username
 *            The WS-Security username.
 * @param password
 *            The WS-Security password.
 * 
 * @throws java.lang.RuntimeException
 *             This exception will be thrown if a SOAPException occurs when
 *             modifying the message.
 */
private void addWSSecurityHeader(SOAPMessageContext smc, String username,
        String password) throws java.lang.RuntimeException {

    try {
        // Get the SOAP Header
        SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();
        SOAPHeader header = message.getSOAPHeader();
        if (header == null) {
            // Create header as it doesn't already exist
            message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().addHeader();
            header = message.getSOAPHeader();
        }

        // Add WS-Security SOAP Header
        SOAPElement heSecurity = header.addChildElement("Security",
                WSSEPrefix, WSSENamespace);
        heSecurity.addAttribute(message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope()
                .createName("mustUnderstand", SOAPENVPrefix,
                        SOAPENVNamespace), "1");

        // Add the Usernametoken element to the WS-Security Header
        SOAPElement heUsernameToken = heSecurity.addChildElement(
                "UsernameToken", WSSEPrefix, WSSENamespace);

        // Add the Username element to the UsernameToken Element
        heUsernameToken.addChildElement("Username", WSSEPrefix,
                WSSENamespace).addTextNode(username);

        // Add the Password element to the UsernameToken Element
        SOAPElement hePassword = heUsernameToken.addChildElement(
                "Password", WSSEPrefix, WSSENamespace);
        hePassword.addAttribute(message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope()
                .createName("Type"), WSSEPasswordText);
        hePassword.addTextNode(password);

    } catch (SOAPException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "Failed to add WS-Security header to request", e);
    }
  }
  }
```