# Send additional data to Workday

Tags: ruby, api, workday-api

I am working on sending some additional data for a workday using this endpoint [Edit_Worker_Additional_Data](https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Staffing/v38.1/Edit_Worker_Additional_Data.html). However, it lacks the documentation as what type of data they are expecting, hence, I am getting validation errors. I have tried various combinations but all in vain.

I took some guidance from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316664/edit-worker-additional-data-using-workday-api) but getting `cus namespace` error as I don't know where and how he initialized that namespace. Data for the custom field that I want to send:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Custom List | T-Shirt Sizes |
| Custom Field Type Name | T-Shirt Sizes |
| Web Service Alias | tShirtSize |
|  |  |
| **List Value Name** | **Web Service Alias** |
| M - Xs | mXs |
| M - S | Ms |

Given below is the XML request body that I am sending

```
<soapenv:Body>
    <bsvc:Edit_Worker_Additional_Data_Request
      xmlns:bsvc="urn:com.workday/bsvc" bsvc:version="v38.1">
      <!-- Optional: -->
      <bsvc:Business_Process_Parameters>
        <!-- Optional: -->
        <bsvc:Auto_Complete>true</bsvc:Auto_Complete>
        <!-- Optional: -->
        <bsvc:Run_Now>true</bsvc:Run_Now>
      </bsvc:Business_Process_Parameters>
      <bsvc:Worker_Custom_Object_Data>
        <bsvc:Effective_Date>2022-11-18</bsvc:Effective_Date>
        <bsvc:Worker_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="string">
          <!-- Zero or more repetitions: -->
          <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="Employee_ID">3671</bsvc:ID>
        </bsvc:Worker_Reference>
        <bsvc:Business_Object_Additional_Data>
          <!-- You may enter ANY elements at this point -->
          <bsvc:tShirtSizes>
            <bsvc:tShirtSizesField>mXs</bsvc:tShirtSizesField>
          </bsvc:tShirtSizes>
        </bsvc:Business_Object_Additional_Data>
      </bsvc:Worker_Custom_Object_Data>
    </bsvc:Edit_Worker_Additional_Data_Request>
  </soapenv:Body>
```

Following are the validation errors that I am getting with different combinations

- Invalid Subelement tShirtSizes-urn:com.workday/bsvc for element Effective_Dated_Web_Service_Additional_Data
- Invalid Subelement T-Shirt_Sizes-urn:com.workday/bsvc for element Effective_Dated_Web_Service_Additional_Data

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've already got an answer. It looks like you need the **Custom Object name Web Service Alias** and the **Custom Field Web Service Alias** for T Shirt and T Shirt Sizes. Assuming T Shirt is a custom object for the **Worker Object Extended**. This can be found by someone with appropriate security access in the Workday environment you are trying to make this for. Looks like this is just a custom list which doesn't really provide the context we are looking for.

- In Workday search for **Custom Object Definitions**
- Search By **Business Process Type**
- Select Edit **Worker Additional Data Event**
- At this point you may have one or more results (most likely one), but based on context it should be appended by **(Effective Dated)**
- From here one should find what you are looking for.

Here is an example of what this looks like for another custom object
[Workday Custom Object Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESklx.png)

Once you get this information it could be something like this:

```
<bsvc:Custom Object's Web Service Alias>
        <bsvc:Custom Field's Web Service Alias>Whatever Type of Value</bsvc:Custom Field's Web Service Alias>
</bsvc:Custom Object's Web Service Alias>
```

Keep in mind that the Custom Fields may be of type boolean so it could also look like this:

```
<bsvc:tShirtSize>
        <!--If field is required send else don't-->
        <bsvc:mXs>true</bsvc:mXs>
        <!--If field is required send else don't-->
        <bsvc:Ms>false</bsvc:Ms>
</bsvc:tShirtSize>
```

Hope this helps!